# Trouble printing a specific div in php with javascript

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to print a specific div without the button showing. When I use document.body the pdf the button is displayed inside. But when i use document.getElementById("customers") all I get is a pdf with black lines. I need some help because I searched and tried many solutions but nothing seems to work.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="customers"> <!-- div that contains my table -->
            <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="20%">
                        <col width="20%">
                            <col width="20%">
                                <col width="20%">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Population</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Chinna</td>
                        <td>1,363,480,000</td>
                        <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                        <td>19.1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>India</td>
                        <td>1,241,900,000</td>
                        <td>March 24, 2014</td>
                        <td>17.4</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="save" onclick="javascript:saveAspdf()"/> <!-- call the js function -->
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
/* js function reffering to jspdf to save a pdf */
    function saveAspdf() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("customers"),function() {
        pdf.save('newDoc.pdf');
    });
    }
```

Comment: "printing a specific div in php with javascript"... the title is misleading, plus there's no PHP here, furthermore it's either PHP or JavaScript but never both!

Comment: I know that there is no php code here.. the table is filled with data that I get from a database.. I just put some examples here.. My main problem is that i cannot print that div..

Comment: That's not relevant to the issue, so talking about PHP is misleading and bothers the understanding of your problem. "`When I use document.body the pdf the button is displayed inside`", is this a behavior you actually want or what? Plus, that grammar... When you append the `body` like you said, do you get the table too or just the button?